# Connection Refused in java

Tags: java, networking, connection

I'm making classes MyServer and MyClient which will recieving and send message to each other.Both classes are on different system but on the same network(i.e my wifi).When both system are running same OS(i.e Windows),it is working perfectly but problem start when MyServer class is running on Windows(Win 7) and MyClient part is running on Linux(Ubuntu 16.04).It is giving Connection refused error.What is the root cause of it.

here is MyClient part...

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.io.*;


class MyClient implements Runnable
{
     static Socket s;
     static DataInputStream cdis;
     static DataOutputStream cdos;    
     static MyClient clientObj;
    public static void main(String... hj)
     {
        clientObj= new MyClient();
         try
         {
               s=new Socket("192.168.1.4",10);
           cdis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
           cdos=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
           clientObj.clientChat();
         }
         catch(IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
     }




     /* This meathod will handle working of Client Chat.
        Internally,another thread "receiver" is started 
        which will handle receiving of message from Server.*/
     public void clientChat()throws IOException
     {
         String send;
         Thread receiver=new Thread(clientObj);
         receiver.start();
         BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         do
         {
             send=input.readLine();
             cdos.writeUTF(send);
        }while(!send.equals("stop"));
           System.out.println("\t\t\t\t Connection Terminated"); 

     }

     /* This meathod will be used to recieve mesage from Client .*/
     public void run()
     {
         String received;
        try{
            do
             {
                received=cdis.readUTF();
                System.out.println("Server : "+received);
            }while(!received.equals("stop"));
              System.out.println("\t\t\t Connection Terminated by Server");
             System.exit(0);            }
        catch(IOException e){}

     }


}
```

Here is MyServer part...

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.io.*;


    class MyServer implements Runnable
    {
         static ServerSocket ss;
         static Socket s;
         static DataInputStream sdis;
         static DataOutputStream sdos;
         static MyServer serverObj;

         public static void main(String... g)throws IOException
         {
            serverObj=new MyServer();
             try{
            ss=new ServerSocket(10);
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t Connection Establishing.....");
            s=ss.accept();
            System.out.println(s);
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t Connection Established");
            sdis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            sdos=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            serverObj.serverChat();
         }
         catch(IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
         }


         /* This meathod will handle working of Server Chat.
            Internally,another thread "receiver" is started 
            which will handle receiving of message from client.*/
         public void serverChat()throws IOException
         {
             String send;
             Thread receiver=new Thread(serverObj);
             receiver.start();
             BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
             do
             {
                send=input.readLine();
                sdos.writeUTF(send);
             }while(!send.equals("stop"));
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t Connection Terminated"); 

         }


         /* This meathod will be used to receive mesage from Client .*/
         public void run()
         {
             String received;
            try{
                do
                 {
                    received=sdis.readUTF();
                    System.out.println("Shadab : "+received);
                }while(!received.equals("stop")); 
                 System.out.println("\t\t\t Connection Terminated by Shadab");
                 System.exit(0);            }
            catch(IOException e){}

         }


    }
```

Comment: Can you "ping" your other system in all cases? Maybe your Linux box is running some firewall; and you simply can't to your windows box at all; or maybe on the port that your windows box is listening on. You can try to do a simple telnet from your linux box to the windows ip:port ... that might give you a hint where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Do they work if they're both running Ubbuntu?

Comment: I am willing to bet there is some software firewall on your ubuntu box that is blocking the connection.

Comment: ah..i almost forgot Ubuntu has ufw firewall...

Comment: that worked...but will it still work if i convert MyServer class for use in android app and leave MyClient part as it is,and then try to connect them?